# Constraining a generic param with Either<L, R>

Tags: c#, functional-programming, either, generic-constraints

I am using MediatR. Requests are decorated like so

```cs
public record GetUserInfoQuery(Guid id) : IRequest<GetUserInfoResponse>;
public record GetUserInfoResponse(Guid id, string Name);
```

I have decided to try to use functional programming in my app (LanguageExt library), so my request now looks like this

```cs
public record GetUserInfoQuery(Guid id) : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, GetUserInfoResponse>>;
public record GetUserInfoResponse(Guid id, string Name);
```

I'm trying to use the functional `Either<L, R>` so I can switch from the following hierarchy

```
Response (has properties like ValidationErrors etc) <|-- SignUpResponse
```

To this

```
          ---- SuccessResponse <|--- SignUpResponse
        / 
Response
        \
          ---- ErrorResponse <|--- (BadRequestResponse / ConflictResponse / etc)
```

When registering my routes against WebApplication I can simply write the following

```cs
app.MapApiRequest<GetUserInfoQuery, GetUserInfoResponse>("/some/url");
```

which uses the following extension

```cs
public static WebApplication MapApiRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(this WebApplication app, string url)
    where TRequest : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>
    where TResponse : SuccessResponse
{
    app.MapPost(
        url,
        ([FromBody] TRequest request, [FromServices] IMediator mediator) => mediator.Send(request).AsHttpResultAsync());
    return app;
}
```

The AsHttpResultAsync() returns the relevant HTTP status based on the successful response, or the type of ErrorResponse I receive in as the result...

```cs
public static class EitherExtensions
{
    public static IResult AsHttpResult<TError, TSuccess>(this Either<TError, TSuccess> source)
        where TError : ErrorResponse
        where TSuccess : SuccessResponse
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        IResult json =
            source.Match(
                Right: x => Results.Json(x),
                Left: x =>
                    x switch
                    {
                        ConflictResponse x => Results.Conflict(x),
                        BadRequestResponse x => Results.BadRequest(x),
                        UnauthorizedResponse _ => Results.Unauthorized(),
                        _ => Results.StatusCode(500)
                    });
        return json;
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> AsHttpResultAsync<TError, TSuccess>(this Task<Either<TError, TSuccess>> source)
        where TError : ErrorResponse
        where TSuccess : SuccessResponse
    =>
        (await source).AsHttpResult();
}
```

This ties everything up nicely. There is nowhere I can get the request/response combination wrong (because of `IRequest<TResponse>`), and this works as a generic constraint because I am able to use `Either<,>` as my constraint wrapped in `Mediator.IRequest<>` (`where TRequest : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>, where TResponse: SuccessResponse`).

But my problem now is that I am trying to add FluentValidation to my pipeline. The following gets triggered because I am specifying the exact response type SignUpResponse.

```cs
public class MediatRValidatingMiddleware<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>, IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, SignUpResponse>>
```

//But that is not what I need. What I need is an open generic so it will execute for all request types, like so...

```cs
where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>, IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, SignUpResponse>>
```

But this doesn't work because Either<L, R> is a struct and so isn't define as `Either<in L, in R>` and so cannot be typecast from `Either<ErrorResponse, SuccessResponse>` to `Either<ErrorResponse, SignUpResponse>`, meaning the `is` check in `MediatR` will return false and my middleware won't get called.

I'm trying to like functional, but it is fighting me back and it seems to be a better fighter.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but shouldn't that be `where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>, IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>`?

Comment: *"[FP] is fighting me back"* Or perhaps it's the frameworks you've chosen to use that are fighting you back...

Comment: FWIW, [C#'s `in` keyword is a specialisation of the more general concept of a covariant functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/10/25/functor-variance-compared-to-cs-notion-of-variance). Since [Either is a (bi)functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/01/14/an-either-functor), you may be able to write the necessary mapping code yourself, if MediatR gives you an extensibility point for it, that is.

Comment: Circling back to my first comment, there's nothing in FP that inherently prevents you from doing things like this, but the frameworks in question may come with built-in assumptions (about how you'd want to use them) that fit poorly with the FP way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was (unsurprisingly) that I needed to wrap the calls with other calls rather than use the MediatR pipeline. So I created an IDispatcher interface.

In `Program.cs`...

```
app.AddUserUseCases();
```

The route setup for users...

```cs
public static class UserUseCases
{
    public static WebApplication AddUserUseCases(this WebApplication app) => app
        .MapApiRequest<SignUpCommand, SignUpResponse>("/api/v1/users/sign-up")
        .MapApiRequest<SignInCommand, SignInResponse>("/api/v1/users/sign-in");
}
```

`MapApiRequest` extension...

```cs
public static class WebApplicationExtensions
{
    public static WebApplication MapApiRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(this WebApplication app, string url)
        where TRequest : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>
        where TResponse : SuccessResponse
    {
        app.MapPost(
            url,
            ([FromBody] TRequest request, [FromServices] IDispatcher<TRequest, TResponse> dispatcher)
            => 
                dispatcher.ExecuteAsync(request).AsHttpResultAsync());
        return app;
    }
}
```

`IDispatcher` interface...

```cs
public interface IDispatcher<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>
{
    ValueTask<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>> ExecuteAsync(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

`Dispatcher` implementation, with validation...

```cs
public class Dispatcher<TRequest, TResponse> : IDispatcher<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>>
{
    private readonly IMediator Mediator;
    private readonly ImmutableArray<IValidator<TRequest>> Validators;

    public Dispatcher(IMediator mediator, IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(validators);
        Mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
        Validators = validators.ToImmutableArray();
    }

    public async ValueTask<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>> ExecuteAsync(
        TRequest request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var errors = ImmutableArray.Create<ValidationError>();
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        foreach (IValidator<TRequest> validator in Validators)
        {
            var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken);
            if (!validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                errors = errors.AddRange(
                    validationResult.Errors.
                        Select(x => new ValidationError(Key: x.PropertyName, Message: x.ErrorMessage)));
            }

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
        }
        if (errors.Any())
            return new BadRequestResponse(errors);

        try
        {
            Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse> mediatorResult = await Mediator.Send(request, cancellationToken);
            return mediatorResult;
        }
        catch (DbConflictException)
        {
            return new ConflictResponse();
        }
        catch (DbUniqueIndexViolationException e)
        {
            return new ConflictResponse($"{e.PropertyName} must be unique");
        }
        catch
        {
            return new UnexpectedErrorResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the `AsHttpResultAsync` extension to convert it to an HTTP response...

```cs
public static class EitherExtensions
{
    public static IResult AsHttpResult<TResponse>(this Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse> source)
        where TResponse : SuccessResponse
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        IResult json =
            source.Match(
                Right: x => Results.Json(x),
                Left: response =>
                    response switch
                    {
                        BadRequestResponse x => Results.BadRequest(x),
                        ConflictResponse x => Results.Conflict(x),
                        UnauthorizedResponse _ => Results.Unauthorized(),
                        UnexpectedErrorResponse _ => Results.StatusCode(500),
                        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
                    });
        return json;
    }

    public static async ValueTask<IResult> AsHttpResultAsync<TResponse>(this ValueTask<Either<ErrorResponse, TResponse>> source)
        where TResponse: SuccessResponse
    =>
        (await source).AsHttpResult();
}
```

A command handler can then be written like so...

```cs
public class SignUpCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<SignUpCommand, Either<ErrorResponse, SignUpResponse>>
{
    public async Task<Either<ErrorResponse, SignUpResponse>> Handle(
        SignUpCommand request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (........) return new BadRequestResponse(.....); fail
        return new SignUpResponse(); // success
    }
}
```